# Predicate Method yes/no/maybe response

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program where the run method calls a predicate method that asks someone "Do you want to go to a movie tonight?". If the user enters "yes" to the question I want the program to say "Ok. Let's go tonight." If the user enters "no" I want the program to print "That's cool lets go next week." But if the user enters "maybe" I want my program to say "it's a yes or no question" then ask the question again "Do you want to go to go to a movie tonight? " and then wait for a user to enter a response again. 
  
The problem I' having is if the user enters "maybe" the program says "it's a yes or no question" then automatically prints "that's fine lets go next week." How do i fix this incorrect logic in my program? This is a question in the chapter focusing on parameter passing in my book. Did I correctly design my program to pass the string value from the run method to the isYesorNo method for what I'm trying to write?

```
import acm.program.*;
public  class MoviesTonight extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        String answer = readLine("do you want to go to a movie tonight?");
        if (isYesorNo(answer)) {
            println("Ok. Let's go tonight");
        } else
            println("that's cool let's go next week");
    }

    private boolean isYesorNo(String response) {
        while (!response.equals("yes") && !response.equals("no")) {
            println("it's a yes or no question");
            break;
        }
        return (response.equals("yes"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the suggestions already provided, the `isYesOrNo` method contains a significant error, which is in fact the answer to your base question:

> The problem I'm having is if the user enters "maybe" the program says "it's a yes or no question" then automatically prints "that's fine lets go next week." How do i fix this incorrect logic in my program?

```
return (response.equals("yes"));
```

If the response is 'maybe', then it does not equal 'yes', and the return will be `false` -- this is why it immediately prints, "that's cool let's go next week". That is in fact the 'else' condition you supplied for `if(isYesOrNo(answer))`.

As it stands, you're checking to see if the response is yes/no, starting a `while` loop which runs if it isn't yes/no, breaking the `while` loop prematurely, and then returning `false` on one of the conditions which spawned the `while` loop in the first place (read: not 'yes'), which finally gets handled as a 'no' (which may not be the case).

Try something like the following, if you want to use if-else:

```
public void askQuestion(){
    String response = readline("Do you want to go to a movie tonight?");
    getYesNoResponse(response);
}

public void getYesNoResponse(String answer){
    if (answer.equals("yes"){
        //print the yes response
    } else if (answer.equals("no") {
        //print the no response
    } else {
        askQuestion();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a enum for returning the answer if you want something other than true/false, but still a discrete set of values.

For example:

```
enum Answer {

   YES,
   NO,
   MAYBE
}
```

Then switch on the enum instead of if/else (down to personal preference, I think a switch statement is cleaner), putting all in a while loop:

```
boolean yesOrNo = false;

while (!yesOrNo) {

    Answer answer = readAnswer("do you want to go to a movie tonight?");

    switch (answer) {

    case ANSWER.YES:
    println("Ok. Let's go tonight");
    yesOrNo = true;
        break;

    case ANSWER.NO:
        println("that's cool let's go next week");
        yesOrNo = true;
        break;

    default:
        println("it's a yes or no question");
        break;
    }
}
```

So basically if the answer is MAYBE, `yesOrNo` doesn't get set to true so the while loop is executed again when the condition is checked.

The `readAnswer` method should be a private static helper method and return the correct enum value based on the input string. Either do this by using an if/else or switch statement on the string.

Comment: you could replace the MAYBE case with Default.  That way, if they enter anything other than yes or no, they'll get the other third response

Comment: @datguy Good call edited it now. Using default means it will work using true/false without the enum.

Comment: Changed `readLine` to `readAnswer`, seems to make more sense in this context if its returning an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. The logic is wrong. If the input is `"maybe"`, then your `isYesOrNo` will print out `"it's a yes or no question"`, but then returns `false`, which gives the additional (problematic) output `""that's cool let's go next week"`.
2. The `break` in the loop does not make sense, which is the real problem. The loop should continue unless the condition is meet, it should break out on the first execution of the loop.

Comment: if i don't use break the program will continuously print "it's a yes or no question" and it won't stop.

Comment: Yes, because you did not get the new input. You should add another line to get a new input from `readLine`.

Comment: add another input line inside isYesorNo method or in the run method?

Comment: It should be in the loop in the `isYesOrNo` method, but yes, it's messing up the naming and intentions a little bit.

Comment: @ziyawei If i type readLine("do you want to go to the movies tonight") inside the while loop inside the isYesorNo method the program does what I want it to do in terms of asking the question again but if the user enters "yes" or "no" it does not print "Ok..." or "that's cool.." it just keeps asking the question over and over no matter what the user enters. In other words the program does not stop if i do that.

Comment: @adamjmarkham This is a better way to organize it, and it could simplify the logic quite a bit.

Comment: you need to move the loop out of isYesorNo, and into your run method.  You are trying to do two different things in isYesorNo (check for a valid answer and translate the answer into a boolean). As a result the behavior doesn't match the method name.